# FX Long/Short Positions datasource

Tags: fx, market-data, longshort

I was wondering if there is any free resources where I can see/ download total FX long/short positions (size or at least number of contracts) in the market currently?

Comment: What market exactly? FX Futures?

Comment: Exactly FX Futures

Comment: https://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/CommitmentsofTraders/index.htm - Financials